# disable default stylesheets in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I use view - page style option to disable style-sheet. Or I can use this add-on...
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/disable-css/

1) But I will like to know if there is any way to load the web-page without it's stylesheet. This will help me on a really slow internet connection.

2) There is no default short-cut key for View - Page Style - No style option.

Comment: This is a question for superuser.com

Comment: I think that css isn't that big a load issue, blocking images will help out more no?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) But I will like to know if there is any way to load the web-page without it's stylesheet. This will help me on a really slow internet connection.

If you want to block the loads of stylesheets you can use the [policeman addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/policeman/), it implements a [content policy filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIContentPolicy) that can distinguish various types of requests (including stylesheets) and block them according to user-configurable filters